# can we display multiple activities in a single activities?

Tags: android

I want to know if we can display multiple activities in a single activity using ActivityGroup.
Can anyone please help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Serenity.

Comment: Bear in mind that this only works for your own activities (not ones provided by Android or other applications). Also, bear in mind that this uses up a fair bit more memory (mostly stack, but also heap).

Answer (score 0):

1. extend it to your activitygroup class.

`Class A extends ActivityGroup{}`

2. Get the `LocalActivityManager`
3. Set the content view as shown below

`this.setContentView(activity.getWindow().getDecorView());`

Where activity -> reference of the activity which you would like to display.

```
Class B extends Activity{
//in onCreate()
Activity activity = this;
}
```

As seen in coderanch.com